# Output cache for page that varies by several DropDownList controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

Is there a way to use Output cache for the page that varies by several DropDownList controls?

I thought about using Cache variables to cache several elements of the page and read them based on the values that I get from the DDLs from codebehind. But the problem is that I don't want the data to be cache "Forerver", and I don't want to change the default Cache duration for the entire site.

I know that for outputcache I get decide the timeout of the caching for a specific page, so I think it's the best solution, but I have a problem implementing it with several DDLs.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041819/different-versions-of-output-caching-based-on-selected-values-of-several-dropdow) talks about using `VaryByParam`, but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, the first time a page is loaded (`IsPostBack` false; HTTP method = GET) it will set initial default values for your DDLs.

When the user changes DDL values and submits the page, it is submitted with the HTTP POST method, and `IsPostBack` is true.  Requests using the HTTP POST method are not cached.

One way you may be able to achieve what you want is the following.  This is for a single DDL but can be extended to multiple DDLs.

- Set `AutoPostBack` = true on your DDL
- Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and redirect (`Response.Redirect`) to the same page after modifying the URL to add/update a querystring parameter (e.g. `...&MyDDLIndex=4...`).
- When your page is first loaded (`IsPostBack` = false), initialize the DDL's SelectedIndex  property based on your custom querystring value, with a suitable default if the querystring value is missing or invalid.

By doing this, you will get a new URL for each combination of DDL settings you want.  E.g. with three DDLs, you might have a URL that looks like:

```
`...MyPage.aspx?MyDDL1Index=2&MyDDL2Index=4&MyDDL3Index=5...`
```

You now have unique URLs for each combination of DDL values, and can use VaryByParam to cache versions of this page based on these querystring values.